# Underfull \hbox (badness 1783) in paragraph at lines 42--44

Tags: badness

I have this code, and Underfull `\hbox (badness 1783)` in paragraph at lines 42--44 error.
Can anyone help me fixing this error?

```
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Decomposition Algorithm, Net Nodal Electricity Demands, Robust Optimization, Transmission Switching, Uncertainty Handling.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: It's not an error, but only a warning that the typesetting of keywords is not as good as the high standards of TeX would require. Don't worry, the badness is not really too big.

Comment: egreg is right, don't worry about it.  If you do want to worry about, then we need to see more of the document set-up to help.  As it stands putting your code snippet into a standard IEEEtran document produces no such warning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not understanding the difference between a warning and an error.

Comment: One way to improve this can be to add `\usepackage{microtype}` which gives some flexibility to the fonts.